# Why use outlier data to train random forest regression for the use of filling other missing data

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, kaggle

```
dataAgeNull = data[data["Age"].isnull()]
dataAgeNotNull = data[data["Age"].notnull()]
remove_outlier = dataAgeNotNull[(np.abs(dataAgeNotNull["Fare"]-dataAgeNotNull["Fare"].mean())>(4*dataAgeNotNull["Fare"].std()))|
                      (np.abs(dataAgeNotNull["Family_Size"]-dataAgeNotNull["Family_Size"].mean())>(4*dataAgeNotNull["Family_Size"].std()))                     
                     ]
rfModel_age = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=2000,random_state=42)
ageColumns = ['Embarked', 'Fare', 'Pclass', 'Sex', 'Family_Size', 'Title1', 'Title2','Cabin','Ticket_info']
rfModel_age.fit(remove_outlier[ageColumns], remove_outlier["Age"])

ageNullValues = rfModel_age.predict(X= dataAgeNull[ageColumns])
dataAgeNull.loc[:,"Age"] = ageNullValues
data = dataAgeNull.append(dataAgeNotNull)
data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Why do we use outlier data of "Fare" and "family_size" to train RandomForestRegressor to fill missing data of "Age"?

I tried to understand this code but still cannot figure it out
4

Answer (score 0):

The code works as the following:

```
remove_outlier = dataAgeNotNull[(np.abs(dataAgeNotNull["Fare"]-dataAgeNotNull["Fare"].mean())>(4*dataAgeNotNull["Fare"].std()))|
                      (np.abs(dataAgeNotNull["Family_Size"]-dataAgeNotNull["Family_Size"].mean())>(4*dataAgeNotNull["Family_Size"].std()))                     
                     ]
```

Here you define a dataframe based on the `dataAgeNotNull`dataframe, where the condition is that A or B is valid:

```
A. (np.abs(dataAgeNotNull["Fare"]-dataAgeNotNull["Fare"].mean())>(4*dataAgeNotNull["Fare"].std())
B. (np.abs(dataAgeNotNull["Family_Size"]-dataAgeNotNull["Family_Size"].mean())>(4*dataAgeNotNull["Family_Size"].std())
```

so you only keep the rows where A or B is True.

And then in:

```
rfModel_age.fit(remove_outlier[ageColumns], remove_outlier["Age"])

ageNullValues = rfModel_age.predict(X= dataAgeNull[ageColumns]
```

You are predicting the Age based on the features in the `ageColumns`. The remove_outlier is only a new dataframe, where some outliers are excluded.

Comment: Then why isn't it using all the data to predict the missing 'Age' value. Isn't it more accurate in this way. Why does it have to use the data that meet either one of the two condition to fit into the random forest regressor?

Comment: sometimes it makes sense to exclude outliers to improve the algorithm. An outlier is a point which occures not often, so the idea is to get the most points right and accept that the outliers will not get predicted right, you improve the overall prediction quality probably if you reduce outlier, so that the algorithm can understand the main flow

Comment: But isn't the data meeting this (np.abs(dataAgeNotNull["Fare"]-dataAgeNotNull["Fare"].mean())>(4*dataAgeNotNull["Fare"].std()) means that it's an outlier?